# How do I toggle button state and display a message after submitting a form in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm a beginner learning to use React. I've got a small component that contains a form using emailJS's recommended implementation. It successfully sends the emails, but there is no feedback to the user once the form is submitted.

Ideally I'd like to animate the button itself and show 'Message Sent!' once the button is clicked. Short of that, I would accept displaying a message somewhere that I could style.

How would I go about doing this?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

const MessageMe = props =>{
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('servicekey', 'templatekey', form.current, 'publickey')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          e.target.reset();
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="messageme-container">
    <form className="messageme-form" ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <div className="namebox">
      <input className="messageme-input" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" name="user_name" /></div>
      <div className="mailbox">
      <input className="messageme-input" placeholder="Your Email" type="email" name="user_email" /></div>
      <div className="bodybox">
      <textarea className="messageme-body" placeholder="Write me a message!" name="message" /></div>
      <button className="messageme-button" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MessageMe;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do. Use of the useState hook like follows:
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Send Message");

As soon as the user clicks the send button, and you enter the handler, set the button text to the intermediate state(sending...). Then, depending on success and failure, update the text inside button component accordingly.

```
setButtonText("Sending...");
...
.then(() => {
    // When sending is a success, set the button text accordingly
    setButtonText("Sent Successfully");
    ...
})
.catch(() => {
    // When there is an error, set the button text accordingly
    setButtonText("Sending Failed");
    ...
})
```

Just render your button component as follows:

```
<button className="messageme-button" type="submit">{buttonText}</button>
```

Hope this helps!. Also, if you want to make the UI more beautiful but don't want to dive in a lot of CSS and JS Logic, you can try out the LoadingButton from Google's Material UI.